# The first video will not load in iPad using Flexslider if set to "slide"

Tags: video, flexslider

This is a very odd problem and I am stumped. I have a Flexslider with HTML5 videos. It works perfectly on my laptop in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. It works fine on the iPad too except for the first video. It just loads and loads and never plays. If I change of order of the videos, it is still whatever video is first that won't load so I know it isn't that particular video. If I change the animation setting to "fade" it loads just fine. It just won't load that first video if set to "slide". I have other settings in flexslider but if I remove them all and leave them to their defaults, same problem. I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem by hooking into the start and after APIs and then cloning the video, removing the original, and then adding the video back.

```
            after: function(slider) {
                var clone =  jQuery('.flex-active-slide .video-container video').clone();
                jQuery('.flex-active-slide .video-container video').remove();
                jQuery('.flex-active-slide .video-container').append(clone);
            },
            start: function(slider) {
                var clone =  jQuery('.flex-active-slide .video-container video').clone();
                jQuery('.flex-active-slide .video-container video').remove();
                jQuery('.flex-active-slide .video-container').append(clone);
            },
```